# index of active slide in angular ui.bootstrap.carousel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to synchronize the movement of an angular bootstrap directive carousel with an animation of another image.

i.e. when the carousel switches to show the 5th slide, I want to show the 5th image from some array.

I am guessing that the "angular way" to do something like this would be to bind the current index of the slide to some common "upper in the hierarchy" scope and then create a directive that will show the Nth image from my second data source.

but It just does not seem as if the carousel controller is exposing this information...

how do I "extract/bind to" the index of the current slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use {{$index}} within the scope of your slides to access the active slide index

Comment: I actually ended up using my own directive instead of the bootstrap carousel but thanks for the info.